# Add contact to Droid using MonoDroid

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin.droid

I am developing a droid app using Xamarin and can add Phone, EMail Company Name, but I cannot figure out what constants to use to add an address.

I am using code like this:

```
//Name
builder = ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri);
builder.WithValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, 0);
builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.ContentItemType);
builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DisplayName, _contactObj.Name);
builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FamilyName, _contactObj.LastName);
builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GivenName, _contactObj.FirstName);
builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MiddleName, _contactObj.MiddleInitial);
builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.Prefix, _contactObj.Prefix);
builder.WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.Suffix, _contactObj.Suffix);
ops.Add(builder.Build());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal`. Complete information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.html). Thanks!